Mock types of function argument in FastAPI
We are testing our FastAPI app using pytest and, only for the testing process, we are using SQLite as DB. Given that we have some UUID types in our models (that only works in Postgres and not in SQLite) those models are changed from UUID to str. The problem happens when we run our test, there are functions that have UUID type definition in the arguments, like this:
def myFunction(arg1: int, arg2: uuid.UUID):
    mydb.query(id==arg2)
...

When the test call any function with that type definition any str is converted to UUID, so the call to mydb.query gets a UUID type instead a str and generates an error (because SQLite doesn't support UUID).
In the test we tried to mock uuid.UUID like this:
@patch('mycode.uuid.UUID', new=str)
def test_mytest1():
....

But that generate an error in Fastapi type validation:
Fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'uuid.UUID'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

We tried to solve that error but couldn't find any information or post related to solve it. Any help (to fix the error or other way to get rid of/mock the UUID)?

This is why testing in a different DB to the one you're actually using is a bad idea. Unless you're willing to only use the intersection of features both support (in this case not the actual UUID type, just store it as a string), you have to hack around the difference. Use e.g. a test container instead.
